# Html select item change event doesn't work

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery

This method is using another page and its working but doesn't work in this page. It does not enter this method.

I have `alert('its came here');` command which is not working, it doesn't appear. Please help me friends

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#yedek_parca_adi").change(function(){
    alert('its came here');
    var secilenYedekParcaId = $("#yedek_parca_adi").val();

    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "./Pages/Tamir_Islemler/Yedek_Parca_Islemleri.php",
      data: {
        secilenYedekParcaId: secilenYedekParcaId,
        paramYedekParcaStokIslemleri: "YedekParcayaGoreBilgiGetir"
      },
      dataType: "JSON",
    }).done(function(json_gelen_cevap) {
      if (json_gelen_cevap.length > 0) {
        document.getElementById('makine_cinsi').value = json_gelen_cevap[0].makine_cinsi;
        document.getElementById('kritik_stok_adet').value = json_gelen_cevap[0].kritik_stok_adeti;
      }
    }).fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorMessage) {
      alert("Bir hata oluştu" + textStatus + errorMessage);
    });
  }).change();
});
```

Html and php codes :

```
 <div class="append-icon">
                          <?php
                          $yedek_parcalar_list = array();
                          array_push( $yedek_parcalar_list, $yedek_parca_islemleri->yedek_parcalari_cek() );
                          ?>
                          <select name="yedek_parca_adi" id="yedek_parca_adi" class="form-control">
                            <?php

                            for ( $i = 0; $i < count( $yedek_parcalar_list[ 0 ] ); $i++ ) {
                              echo '<option value="' . $yedek_parcalar_list[ 0 ][ $i ][ "yedek_parca_id" ] . '">' . $yedek_parcalar_list[ 0 ][ $i ][ "yedek_parca_adi" ] . '</option>';
                            }
                            echo '</select>';

                            ?>
                          </select>
                        </div>
```

İts working insert select option.But It does not enter change method.

[image]

Comment: Typo. `$('yedek_parca_adi')` is not a valid selector. From the use later in the code I presume you've missed the `#` prefix on it.

Comment: $("#yedek_parca_adi").change(function(){  I trying this but not working again

Comment: Doesnt came alert command.It does not enter this method.

Comment: I was edited code.İnserting html and php codes for you

Answer (score 0):

1- You have to be shure that jquery is loaded. You can add this line before calling your .js file to be shure (remove it after your test) :

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js" integrity="sha256-/xUj+3OJU5yExlq6GSYGSHk7tPXikynS7ogEvDej/m4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

2- You also have a .change() at the end of your .change() :

```
$("#yedek_parca_adi").change(function(){ ... }).change();
```

3- Your for loop until

```
count($yedek_parcalar_list[ 0 ])
```

so I suppose that

```
$yedek_parca_islemleri->yedek_parcalari_cek()
```

returns an array ?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you bro I was fixed problems.somewhere } missing in js codes :(